# Can't store one field

Tags: php, laravel

I have course and course is having questions and answers. So i'm trying to store course_id questions, answers and correct answer. questions, answers and correct answers stores. I don't have problem with it but i can't store course_id on course_id it's stores NULL.

```
 $data = request()->validate([
            'questions.*.course_id' => '',
            'questions.*.question' => 'required',
            'questions.*.answers.*.answer' => 'required',
            'questions.*.answers.*.correct' => '',
        ], [
            'questions.*.course_id.required' => '',
            'questions.*.question.required' => '',
            'questions.*.answers.*.answer.required' => ''
        ]);

foreach ($data['questions'] as $key => $q) {
    $question = $CourseQuestion->create(['question' => $q['question']]);
    $question->answers()->createMany($data['questions'][$key]['answers']);
}
return redirect()->back();
```

In blade

```
 <input name="questions[1][question]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.0.question') }}">
                            <input type="text" value="{{ $c->id }}" name="questions[1][course_id]">

<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="questions[1][answers][1][correct]">
                                    <input name="questions[1][answers][1][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.1.answers.0.answer') }}" >
```

Whats i'm doing wrong?

Comment: So look at the schema and tell us how the `id` column is defined

Comment: What's the model look like? Specifically check the `fillable` and `guarded` attributes to ensure `course_id` is mass assignable.

Comment: <input type="text" value="{{ $c->id }}" name="questions[1][course_id]"> ID  /     protected $guarded = ['*'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'course_id', 'question'
    ];

Comment: You're sending `$q['question']` to create, but I don't see where you're passing anything else in.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that i was not passing course_id. So i changed my store function

```
 public function store(CourseQuestion $CourseQuestion)
    {
        $course = Course::find(request()->get('courseId'));

        $data = request()->validate([
            'questions.*.question' => 'required',
            'questions.*.answers.*.answer' => 'required',
            'questions.*.answers.*.correct' => '',
        ], [
            'questions.*.question.required' => '',
            'questions.*.answers.*.answer.required' => ''
        ]);

        foreach ($data['questions'] as $key => $q) {
            $question = $course->questions()->create(['question' => $q['question']]);
            $question->answers()->createMany($data['questions'][$key]['answers']);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I'm getting now current course and then with that course adding questions and then answers : )

Thanks all for response <3